# MFC CWebBrowser2 events

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Does anyone know what event fires before (and after) a CWebBrowser2 (MFC) embedded browser control loads an image?

I know that when a webpage/URL loads an event OnBeforeNavigate2 occures and after the load is complete an event OnDocumentCompleteExplorer happens.

But what about when the webpage that you are navigate to requests an image to be loaded? What event(s) happen?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

For each resource that your webpage needs webbrowse will fire onbeforenavigate2 and navigate2 events

Comment: That is what I would expect. However, the page resources do not fire OnBeforeNavigate2, OnNavigateComplete2 or OnDocumentCompleteComplete. The OnDocumentComplete event happens after the entire webpage is loaded and it's URL variable indicates the HTML document source rather than any IMG or other resource. Any other ideas?

Comment: as per my knowledge  OnDocumentComplete is fired only on webpage is loaded.